# Self biased transistor current limiter

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, analog, bjt, npn

I am analysing the below self biased transistor circuit and have some questions:

[image]

1. Why does the transistor in self biased arrangement never go into saturation for a light load?
2. When the  emitter terminal is shorted, the maximum 'ie' passing t through the short is 552mA, while'ib' is 231mA. What values decide this maximum 'ie' current when designing a current limiter?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are operating the BJT outside its limits. The BJT you are simulating has a maximum collector current of 50 mA.

> Why transistor in self bias arrangement never goes into saturation for light load ?

There's local feedback via the load resistor, so the circuit works as a constant current source. Its current limit is:

$$
\mathrm{I_L=\frac{V_B-V_{BE-Q1}}{R_{LOAD}}}
$$

where V<sub>B</sub> is simply the voltage at base node w.r.t. GND:

$$
\mathrm{I_L=\frac{V_2 - I_B\cdot R_1-V_{BE-Q1}}{R_{LOAD}}}
$$

So you can't expect saturation here because the BJT is operating at active region.

> ... what values decide this maximum 'ie' current if current limit is to be designed ?

When you short the 1mR resistor what you'll get is 300R resistor and base-emitter diode of the transistor connected in series and loading the voltage source. If you write a KVL for this:

$$
\mathrm{V_2=I_B\ R_1+V_{BE-Q1}}
$$

It's obvious that a significantly high current will flow through the base-emitter diode, so we can't simply assume its voltage drop to be 0.6 .. 0.7V. Instead, we can take it as 1V or even higher. For 1V the base current can be calculated as

$$
\mathrm{I_B=\frac{V_2-V_{BE-Q1}}{R_2}=\frac{74-1}{300}=243\ mA}
$$

which is quite close to the value you see on your simulation.

As for the collector current, BJTs DC current gain drops significantly for higher currents. The simulation model of the transistor determined that the DC current gain will be ~2.5 for ~0.25A of base current. If you have specified an output resistance for the voltage source then it'll contribute to the current limit as well.

Comment: There isnt any feedback in the circuit.

Comment: The voltage drop on the load creates a variable potential in the emitter, that's what Rohat was talking about when he said "*There's local feedback via the load resistor*".

Comment: Rohat, I guess you had a typo in your last expression, it should be 74-1, not 71. Not that it changes the conclusion.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen oh, sorry. Yes, it should have been 74-1. *(Maybe I took it as 72-1, I don't know LOL)*. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @MissMulan there is. Look carefully. And remember the common emitter amplifier with emitter resistor. What was the effect of that resistor in quiescent/biasing? Same thing applies here.

Comment: @RohatKılıç , Thanks for the  detailed explaination.  I got the point . Constant current limit (550mA) will eventually  be decided by the Beta of transistor and R1 value as during short condition there  would not be any load resistor. is that correct ? Thanks